# where does my sftp passwords save in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04, I used to connect to a server using sftp (like I added my server address as sftp://... and chose the option to remember my password forever.)

[image]

Now I forgot my password :)
I still can connect to server when I click on my server in the `+ other locations` in the ubuntu because it remembers my password, but I dont remember it myself.
I was wandering if there is a way to find and look up what was my password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system app "Keys & Passwords" (or similar - I'm using a non-English language version of Ubuntu so don't know the exact English name), you can find it in the applications menu. Open this app, go to "Passwords database" tab and you should find your password stored there somewhere, along with other stored passwords (see screen below).

[image]

Double click on the entry corresponding to your stored password and you should see a screen like below.

[image]

Click on the key image in the password field and you will see the password.

BTW. I think that a better site for this question is [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) - maybe someone of the admins can migrate the question there...

Comment: Thank you that was the way,
Just as a summary it was in: Passwords and Keys -> Login -> we can see the login info here